# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack" when installing gems

Tags: installation, bundle

**I get the below when running bundle install on haml, bootstrap sass and simple_form gems:**

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

simple_form (~> 3.0.2) was resolved to 3.0.2, which depends on
  actionpack (~> 4.0)
```

**My Gemfile is shown below:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'

gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.2'
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please? thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I found this and successfully install that:

this:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1485

that:

```
gem 'simple_form', github: 'elsurudo/simple_form', branch: 'rails-5.1.0'
```